# Why i am not able to draw rectangle on canvas in Android?

Tags: android, android-graphics

```
public class OverlayView extends View {
    private Rect rectangle;
    private Paint paint;
    int l,t,r,b;

    private final List<DrawCallback> callbacks = new LinkedList<DrawCallback>();

    public OverlayView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public void addCallback(final DrawCallback callback) {
        callbacks.add(callback);
    }

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.v("drawrectindraw",String.valueOf(l)+" "+String.valueOf(t)+" "+String.valueOf(r)+" "+String.valueOf(b));

    rectangle = new Rect(l, t, r, b);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
}
    public OverlayView(Context context, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super(context);
        this.l = l;
        this.t = t;
        this.r = r;
        this.b = b;
        rectangle = new Rect(this.l, this.t, this.r, this.b);

        Log.v("drawrect",String.valueOf(this.l)+" "+String.valueOf(t)+" "+String.valueOf(r)+" "+String.valueOf(b));
    }

    public interface DrawCallback {
        public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas);
    }
}
```

I am passing rectangle values from my activity to my custom view class to continuously draw rectangle on the screen..

Unable to understand why i am 0 0 0 0 in onDraw method,
in my constructor i am able to get proper values.

e.g drawrect: 153 494 535 875

Log

> 02-25 18:02:28.795 30639-30639/V/drawrectindraw: 0 0 0 0
>
> 02-25 18:02:29.025 30639-31224/V/drawrect: 153 494 535 875
>
> 02-25 18:02:29.164 30639-30639/V/drawrectindraw: 0 0 0 0
>
> 02-25 18:02:29.366 30639-31412/V/drawrect: 153 494 535 875
>
> 02-25 18:02:29.516 30639-30639/V/drawrectindraw: 0 0 0 0
>
> 02-25 18:02:29.745 30639-30767/V/drawrect: 199 481 517 801
>
> 02-25 18:02:29.919 30639-30639/V/drawrectindraw: 0 0 0 0

Comment: how do you add your `OverlayView` to the UI tree? by calling `new OverlayView(Context, int, int, int, int)` and then `someParent.addView()`?

Comment: just did this OverlayView overlayView = new OverlayView(MyActivity.this,faceRect.left,faceRect.top,faceRect.right,faceRect.bottom);

Comment: and what next are you doing with `overlayView`? do you call `someParentView.addView(overlayView)`?

Comment: thats it, i have the OverlayView in my activity's layout.

Comment: so what do you expect? if you just create a new `OverlayView` and dont add it to your UI tree?

Comment: OverlayView is already added to the Ui tree via xml. if i give static values like this `rectangle = new Rect(199, 481, 517, 801);` its its able to draw the rectangle.

Comment: so if its already added, why do you create a `new OverlayView` then? just use that one which is added in your layout xml

Comment: Thank you so much @pskink addView did the trick

Comment: your welcome, but as i said: if you already have your view in layout xml just use existing view - get it by calling `Activity#findViewById`